Finding Root Form of Verbs using Curiosity-AI/Catalyst
I'm trying to find the root form of a verb. I run text through the pipeline and can identify all tokens which match PartOfSpeech.VERB but I don't know how to continue from there.
This is what I have so far:
const string text = "The disastrous cat runs after the fat field mouse.";
Catalyst.Models.English.Register();

Storage.Current = new DiskStorage(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
var nlp = await Pipeline.ForAsync(Language.English);
var doc = new Document(text, Language.English);
nlp.ProcessSingle(doc);


foreach (var sentence in doc.TokensData)
{
    foreach (var token in sentence)
    {
        if(token.Tag == PartOfSpeech.VERB)
        {
            //  so here I'd like to the root form of the verb
        }
    }
}

Any help is greatly appreciated.

The following code (targeting .NET 8.0) illustrates one method to obtain the root form of a verb from an inflected form.
(I have annonoted, as code comments, the three NuGet packages (with versions) required. Most of the code is identical to your original sample above.)
//// Installed Curiosity.Library v24.10.52882
//// Installed Catalyst v1.0.51118
//// Installed Catalyst.Models.English v1.0.30952

using Catalyst;

using Mosaik.Core;

const string text = "The disastrous cat quickly runs after the fat field mouse.";
Catalyst.Models.English.Register();

Storage.Current = new DiskStorage(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
var nlp = await Pipeline.ForAsync(Language.English);
var doc = new Document(text, Language.English);
nlp.ProcessSingle(doc);

foreach (var span in doc.Spans)
{
    foreach (var token in span.Tokens)
    {
        if (token.POS == PartOfSpeech.VERB)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Root of the verb '{token.Value}' is '{token.Lemma}'.");
        }
    }
}

Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("Complete; press any key.");
Console.ReadKey();

Note: For this specific sentence, I have added an adverb ("quickly") before the verb ("runs"). Without this, the library incorrectly interprets "runs" as a noun. Depending on your source text, this might be an issue for you, but I believe it is separate from the question being asked.
